# get selctbox options text and set it for checkbox label and append checked label to textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have selectbox, Checkbox and TextBox fields, SelectBox field gets its option values from DB, so I don't know how many options will get. I need to append the same no of selectBox options text without first option to be label's text of checkbox field, then when user check some of this checkbox options append what user has checked only in textbox Separated by dash "-"

```html
<select id= "selectbox">
  <option  value="option1">Choice1</option>
  <option  value="option2">Choice2</option>
  <option  value="option3">Choice3</option>
</select>


  <input type="checkbox" id="chckbox">
 <label for="Field3-0">Checkbox1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="chckbox">
 <label for="Field3-1">Checkbox2</label>

  <input id= "textfield" type= "text" >
```

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding your question. I wonder if you can try rephrasing it in a more step by step manner. Also, you specify that you are creating options based on DB values, but you do not specify what server side language (PHP? Ruby? Node?) you are using to get that info and turn it into html. Knowing that will probably be necessary for any of us to answer your question.

Comment: sorry that the question is unclear because english is not my mother tongue, I will try to explain it step by step: 1- I have select box in my form, I dont know how many values this select box will filled out because it get it's values from DB. 2-After this selectbox filled out, I need to take all it's values and set it as checkbox choices. 3- User will chose some of this checkbox choices or check all of them. 4- need to take that choices what user check and concatenate in text box Separated by dash "-".  5- I use web application connected to sql No coding for me to bring data from sql.